# Landscape mode only for video

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

My app support only portrait mode but for video which I am playing from UIWebView in fullscreen should also support landscape mode.I googled a lot and found some answer like by adding notification that I don't to do because there lot notification for other stuff and second that I found working is this code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    var classesToCheckFor = [AnyClass]()

    if let ios7Class = NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController") {
        classesToCheckFor.append(ios7Class)
    }

    if let ios8Class = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController") {
        classesToCheckFor.append(ios8Class)
    }

    for classToCheckFor in classesToCheckFor {
        if (self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.isKindOfClass(classToCheckFor) != nil) {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        }
    }

    return .Portrait
}
```

It is working fine in iOS 9 but not in iOS 8.Anyone knows how to do this for iOS 8.

OR is there any other way that I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution just remove the keyword `self` and it worked fine in both ios 8 and ios 9.Change code is

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    var classesToCheckFor = [AnyClass]()

    if let ios7Class = NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController") {
        classesToCheckFor.append(ios7Class)
    }

    if let ios8Class = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController") {
        classesToCheckFor.append(ios8Class)
    }

    for classToCheckFor in classesToCheckFor {
        if (window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.isKindOfClass(classToCheckFor) != nil) {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        }
    }

    return .Portrait
}
```